# Unit Testing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, easymock

I'm currently trying to complete a piece of Test Driven Development coursework and have ran into a problem with the following code:

```
package stockInformation;

public class StockInformation {

String companyName;

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

private WebService webService;

// Constructor
public StockInformation(int userID) {

    if (webService.authenticate(userID)){
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        companyName = "Not Allowed";
    }
}
}
```

(The if-else is done poorly on purpose so that I can refactor it later on in the assignment)

Web Service which is 'being developed by another team' so needs to be mocked
    package stockInformation;

```
public interface WebService {

public boolean authenticate(int userID);

}
```

Test Class

```
package stockInformation;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class StockInformationTest {

WebService mockWebService;
StockInformation si;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockWebService = createMock(WebService.class);
}

@Test
public void testUserIdAuthentication() {
    int userID = -2;
    si = new StockInformation(userID);
    expect(mockWebService.authenticate(userID)).andReturn(false);
    replay(mockWebService);
    assertEquals("Not Allowed", si.getCompanyName());
    verify(mockWebService); 
}

}
```

When I run the unit test I get a NullPonterException at:

```
if (webService.authenticate(userID)){
```

and

```
si = new StockInformation(userID);
```

I want the unit test to pass :)
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a theory about the value of `webService` when that code runs? What do you think that value is?

Comment: webService is just representing the interface which will have a method authenticate(int userId) which returns true or false depending on whether the given userId meets the validation. There's not supposed to be any actual functionality written in the WebService interface, hence the use of andReturn in the unit test.

Comment: I understand that. Which value do *you* think `webService` has when the code runs?

Comment: I think it will be false because of the andReturn

Comment: `webService` is declared as a value of the type `WebService`. Is `false` a valid value of the type `WebService`?

Comment: I'm guessing not...
I've changed the code in the StockInformation class so that the constructor now includes a WebService which has gotten ride of the NullPointer, but now I'm getting:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
WebService.authenticate(-2)
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()

Comment: Got to the bottom of it :)

Answer (score 0):

You never set the `private WebService webservice` in class `StockInformation`.  You use this in the `StockInformation` constructor and its value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow assign a value to webService field of StockInformation class.

This can be done by reflection or a setter method:

```
public void setWebService(WebService webService) {
    this.webService = webService;
}
```

Then during test execution you set a mock WebService instance to StockInformation instance:

```
si = new StockInformation(userID);
si.setWebService(mockWebService);
```